# Henckel knife model #

Tags: knives

**Which Henckel knife sets sold in higher end department stores in the 1980s?**

My grandma had an excellent set that she bought for $989.00 and I want a set like that or a better made set. They were heavy, made of a non riveted blade with a single black handle. If you know of a knife that is equal to or heavier than that knife, please let me know which knife it is.

I purchased 3 different knife sets from Zwilling and Henckel that were inferior to the set that she had back in the late 80s- early 90s. It was a waste of money trying to find a comparable knife set online.

Comment: Are you asking what knives she bought, what an equal/better set would be or are you looking for heavy knives? It's unclear from the question

Comment: If you’re trying to find a heavy knife, you may want to go to a specialty knife or kitchenwares store.  The online stuff may be less expensive, but you can’t be sure of what you’re going to get (I’ve had a few times when I’m pretty sure I got knockoff items from Amazon Marketplace)

Comment: Hi Dilli, we don't make product recommendations here. So we can't tell you that "model X of company Y is heavy and good quality". Answers to this question will have to be a model number or exact model name of the knife produced back then. I'm not sure how much it will help you though, because it's unlikely that a company has kept the exact production process for 40 years, especially as you've stated that you've tried out their current products and found them to be different.